# React functions and events

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

I am fairly new to react, I was looking at code and I ran into an event 
code inside of a class that looked like

```
 zipValueChanged(event) {
    const zip = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      zipValue: zip,
    })
```

I was wondering why the event function does not have the function keyword anywhere, I did see a binding in the constructor ( this.zipValueChanged = this.zipValueChanged.bind(this);) However, I do not understand why this works.

Thank you so much!

Comment: That just how a class-method is defined

Comment: check [**MDN Doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for more details about class and how to define methods inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (this.zipValueChanged = this.zipValueChanged.bind(this);) binding in constructor was done so that any method defined in the class can work.

You need to bind your method in your constructor in order to work it properly -

**this.yourFunction = this.yourFunction.bind(this);**

Answer (score 1):

This is the new syntax for Class methods definition. You can check out documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

From now on inside a class you can define methods this way :

```
class A{
  render() {
    //your code here
  }
}
```